# JavaScript and document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JS. I put `document.getElementById` in my JS and tried to put that element into a `p` id, but when I click the button, nothing is showing up. What am I doing wrong here? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>GRL Example</title>
<script>
function class_roll() {
    // Car Classes
    var classes = ["B", "A", "S", "R3", "R2", "R1"],
        classToUse = classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length)];
    var elemClass = document.getElementById("croll");
}

function track_roll() {
    // Tracks
    var tracks = ["Clear Springs Circuit", "Festival North Circuit", "Beaumont Circuit", "Finley Dam Circuit", "Gladstone Circuit", "Clifton Valley Trail", "Gladstone Trail"],
        trackToUse = tracks[Math.floor(Math.random() * tracks.length)];
    var elemTrack = document.getElementById("troll");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<p id="croll">Some text here</p>
    <button onclick="class_roll();">Class Roll</button>

<p id="troll">Some text here</p>
    <button onclick="track_troll;">Track Roll</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you changing the value?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You're not doing anything with the found elements. Also, you need `()` here - `onclick="track_troll;"` for the function call to become `onclick="track_troll();"`

Comment: Also, as far as I know languages, you can't call the array `classes` or `tracks` in the same statement that they are defined.

Comment: Maye somthing like this?!
getElemetById("croll").innerHTML= classToUse;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### With First function

```
function class_roll() {
    // Car Classes
    var classes = ["B", "A", "S", "R3", "R2", "R1"],
        classToUse = classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length)];
    var elemClass = document.getElementById("croll");
}
```

You are not performing any action therefore add some action which visible to you. Change it to.

```
function class_roll() {
    // Car Classes
    var classes = ["B", "A", "S", "R3", "R2", "R1"],
        classToUse = classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length)];
    document.getElementById("croll").innerHTML = classToUse ;
}
```

### With Second Function

```
function track_roll() {
    // Tracks
    var tracks = ["Clear Springs Circuit", "Festival North Circuit", "Beaumont Circuit", "Finley Dam Circuit", "Gladstone Circuit", "Clifton Valley Trail", "Gladstone Trail"],
        trackToUse = tracks[Math.floor(Math.random() * tracks.length)];
    var elemTrack = document.getElementById("troll");
}
```

1. There is typo mistake in function name means name what you calling is different from definition name.
2. `document.getElementById("troll").innerHTML = trackToUse ;`
   add this to see the selected option randomly.

Here is repaired code for your assistance

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>GRL Example</title>

</head>

<body>

<p id="croll">Some text here</p>
    <button onclick="class_roll();">Class Roll</button>

<p id="troll">Some text here</p>
    <button onclick="track_roll();">Track Roll</button>

</body>
<script>
function class_roll() {
    // Car Classes
    var classes = ["B", "A", "S", "R3", "R2", "R1"],
        classToUse = classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length)];
    document.getElementById("croll").innerHTML = classToUse ;
}

function track_roll() {

    var tracks = ['a' ,'a' ,'a' ,'a'];
        trackToUse = tracks[Math.floor(Math.random() * tracks.length)];
    document.getElementById("troll").innerHTML = trackToUse ;

}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you SO SO much! I understand it completely now.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to change the value of your element, you'll need to do something with it after you've retrieved it.

For example:

```
function track_roll() {
    // Tracks
    var tracks = ["Clear Springs Circuit", "Festival North Circuit", "Beaumont Circuit", "Finley Dam Circuit", "Gladstone Circuit", "Clifton Valley Trail", "Gladstone Trail"],
        trackToUse = tracks[Math.floor(Math.random() * tracks.length)];
    var elemTrack = document.getElementById("troll");
    elemTrack.InnerHTML = "Test";
}
```